# Box coming out of browser in css web page

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I want a web page which would have an rectangle at the top of the webpage coming from the browser.

I currently have a square created by css, but I am trying to get it to be an square that should come out from the top of the page.
like this
[image from the corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvaK4.jpg)

I am using css with wordpress elementor to create the square

This is my css

```
content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; right:0; 
    z-index:-1;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0fffc1, #7e0fff);
  background-size:200% 200%;
```

the result which is coming out currently is this
[centered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz9bB.jpg)

Comment: `position: fixed;`

Comment: i will try it and let you know. thanks

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Thanks was you was helpful. respponse could have been earlier

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
you can change the size by changing `height` and `width` and also by changing  `right`, you can move it right and left.

```css
.container:before{
  content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
  right:-50px; 
    z-index:-1;
    height:5rem;
    width:10rem;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0fffc1, #7e0fff);
  background-size:200% 200%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the atempt but what i am asking for is that the image should come out from the corner of the browser i.e. some of the part of the object would not be seen. But the one u did every part is shown. Also the object is square/rectangle not circle

Comment: I appreciate what you did, I would test it out that is awesome

Answer (score 0):

We need info about your HTML. I'll assume that the element you want to position is a direct child of the body element (or a pseudo element that belongs to body). In that case you can use `position:absolute` since an absolute positioned element looks for the nearest ancestor, if not It's positioned in the viewport.

Keep that in mind because you may need position fixed or sticky if the above don't apply.

I'm also seeing that you're using a `left:0` and `right:0`; which means that the positioned element will take all the available space on the left and right (It's the same as saying width:100%).

There is more... You're using a width of 100% and the image that you've provided to us doesn't. Also, don't set percentages on height. You could use the `vh`(viewport height) unit in this case.

Finally, I've just created a fiddle that kind of represents what you're looking for.

myFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lucasdavidferrero/4ak6pe8j/41/